# Sending a corporate spammer email to other email spammers, spam lead lists, and spam portals?

Tags: spam, bulk-email

Pardon this edgy question, but I'm sick of getting constant emails from these seo startups, marketing companies, and leads generation services. They literally never leave me alone. I would like to enter the emails of these sales people one time into a box. That box would send their emails and other contact info off to the most amount of seo spammers, diet sites, marketing leadgens, ghana fundgens, 24 hour loans, telco lists, porn mailers, etc as possible, all in 1 click.

Short of me manually going around to crap sites and joining their diet seo newsletters, what would be the best way to go about flooding back a spammer with real spam from a ton of lists? I dont think there is such a tool or service that I know of? Basically I need the shadiest yet largest means to flooding their inbox with real legitimate spam, selling out their email to the most amount of worthless lists, just like they do to the rest of the world, in the least amount of steps as possible.

I thought bot, with a custom domain list or something, but I dunno how well (or fast) that would work out. Is there a way I can just ....donate... their emails to a few select free/uberlists?

Comment: Don't waste your time.  

For a start they are usually using spoofed email addresses or even worse, some poor internet user's email address - trust me on this, I have been the recipient of thousands of bounced and abusive emails after someone used my email as the FROM address.

Comment: I am not sure how much this would work these days, however, I used to post e-mail addresses on a HTML page on my website and let the e-mail harvesters have at it. That used to work! Remember the days back in the 70s when the cards used to fall out of magazines?? What you are proposing is something like filling out hundreds of these cards with a spammers info. It was such a problem back in the day that the cards (called blow in adverts) began to disappear. Too bad the Spam Recycling Center is now closed. Sounds like a fit otherwise.

Comment: @Steve these are real sales people at real companies with real emails. Some of the companies are big, but nonetheless, their sales people are still amateur, spammy, and annoying. One dude has pestered me for a month looking for the "marketing team contact". He is not gonna get it, but apparently he never took the CRM scheduler off so i still get these stupid probes regardless. When one sales guy leaves he gets the old ones contacts, same thing repeats.

Comment: @closetnoc Hah, dude thats actually a brilliantly simple idea!

Comment: If you were brave, you can start your own spam recycler. I cannot find info on why the old one shut down, but I would think that a simple inbox, PERL, and blacklist would do the trick. It could all be automated very easily. SPAM is *unsolicited* so even the ones you are receiving would qualify. My attitude is efum. Nuke me, I will nuke you. Here is something: *You can also report your spam (by forwarding it complete with full headers) to the U.S. government's spam-evidence database run by the FTC at: spam@uce.gov*

Comment: This is an old page, but still something along the same track: https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/ReportingSpam Perhaps there is something for the anti-spam tool or e-mail client you use. You can always simply blacklist the domain name in your anti-spam tool at least. Not as much fun though. Spamassassin allows this. Not sure if you can bounce back a blacklisted e-mail with a notice. Could cause back scatter which can get your domain in trouble so I think I would avoid that option.

Comment: I totally understand your pain. :( Why don't you simply blacklist/filter their email and spend your time working **for** you instead of **against** them? :)

Comment: Spammers know the importance of having inbound spam filters. All you'll be doing is causing the network loading to be worse, the junk you encourage to be sent will either be dropped by the server or the spam filter and I'll bet their servers are more than adequate to handle the extra junk, so while it's soul salve, it's like using a shovel to dig a hole in a pond.

Comment: Also, be careful responding to span with an attack of any sort.  Often these people have way more resources than you do, again trust me on this after my server was DDOSed for 3 day after I forced bounces on a a spammer.. He actually told me it was 'punishment'.  Nowadays I kill spam, but quietly.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to be careful doing something like this as it would technically be classified as spamming as well and can result not just in the box in question being blacklisted byt potentially the entire IP block and even if the entire IP block isn't blacklisted you will find that it is against your providers terms of service. In addition you could potentially open yourself up to unwanted litigation from doing something like this. The best thing to do with spam is mark it as spam so that the sender potentially gets added to blacklists and then delete it from your inbox. A good spam filter will do this automatically for you for most spam emails and when you mark a sender as spam once most spam filters will auutomatically block later similar emails from the same sender.